# Minimum flow to give nodes specific value

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

Is there a known algorithm in graph theory that solves the problem of using the minimum flow to leave nodes with a specific value? In other words, there are multiple sources and sinks that need to be left with certain amounts of deficit and credit. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the credits (deficits) for sources (sinks)?

Comment: Sure, the idea is that there is, for example, an exchange of currency. Some people overall owe money and some people overall are owed money. You want to figure out how to get everyone their money with least amount of money floating around.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is. It is actually called Minimum Cost Flow Algorithm.
I am providing a permanent link to this algorithm: 
[Minimum Cost Flow](http://neddimitrov.org/uploads/classes/201104NFG/Dimitrov-NFGNotes6-v2.pdf)
You will need a LP Solver for generating a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could formulate this as a “[Transportation Problem](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Transportation+Problem)” – with the debtors being the suppliers (of money) and the demand coming from the creditors. The goal is to “transport” the money from one side to the other.

To handle the **objective** (“least amount of money floating around”), we can assume that debtors want to pay as few creditors as they can, and creditors want to get money from as few debtors as feasible.

Let there be ‘*s*’ nodes, one for each supplier (debitor) and ‘*t*’ nodes, one for each creditor. Directed arc’s connect each supplier to each demand node. The cost of moving money over any arc (edge) is 1. (All edges have a very high capacity.)

In a **balanced transportation problem** the total demand will equal the total supply, but that is an idealized case. We can handle the imbalance in the totals of credits and debits by introducing dummy nodes, and dummy edges.

Since we want to use the dummy edges as little as we can, we can assign those edges a higher cost. Consequently, the model will use these edges only as a last resort.

Pictorially,

[image]

**Formulation of this transportation problem:**

X_st is the amount of money (flow) from node s to node t

***Objective***: Min (sum_over_edges) Cost_st * X_st

**Constraints**

```
 (Sum over all edges incoming to demand node t ) X_st >= Demand_t (for each t)
 (Sum over all edges outbound from supply node s ) X_st >= Supply_s (for each s)
 Xst >= 0
```

A couple of other notes:

1. This problem could alternatively also be formulated as a [transshipment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transshipment). You have intermediate staging points (clearing houses for the money).
2. When you have multiple sources and sinks, you can create a “super source” and a “super sink” node, and connect edges to from these super nodes to regular sources and sink nodes, and re-create a min-flow problem.

Once the formulation is done, you can use any MILP solver that you have access to, to obtain the optimal matching of debtors to creditors.

Hope that helps.